# Sending emails to number of email addresses stored in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send email to number of email addresses stored in my database using some query that would send email to only those whose domain is going to be expired within 5 days. I think my query is not running and is not accessing emails from database that is stored in "$to" variable. But when I give a specific email address in "$to", this code sends email to that particular address. But the problem is i want to send email to the email address stored in database whose domain is going to be expired. This is my model database.php. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    database.php model:
    function sendmailto(){
    $query ="select email from domain_detail where expiry_date - curdate()=5"; 

    //$query ="select email from domain_detail where expiry_date < curdate()";


   if($query_result = $this->db->query($query)){

    foreach ($query_result->result() as $domain_list) {
        $to= $domain_list->email;
        //$to = "abcd18@gmail.com";
        $from= "ijkl23@hotmail.com";
        $subject='test cron';
        $message= '<h2> Your domain is going to be expired. Please renew it soon.';
        $headers= "From: $from\n";
        $headers .="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
         if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo 'Message has been sent successfully.';

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Message couldnot send. Please try again!';
    }
}
else{
    echo "No Email Address Found!!";
}


}
```

Comment: in codeigniter,email library is there

Comment: But i am having the problem in query. i think query is not working because when i give specific email address in "$to" it works, i mean it sends email but query is not working... any help??

Answer (score 0):

When you are referencing $domain_list->email; are you sure that $domain_list is an object and not an associative array? Have you tried using $domain_list['email'] instead?

Answer (score 0):

Normal PHP mail() function can sometimes be marked as spam by the receiver. I would suggest trying out phpmailer library: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master

If you using CI maybe try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select email from domain_detail where expiry_date - curdate()=5');

if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{
   foreach($query->result() as $domain_list) 
   {
      // rest of code here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't subtract 2 date or datetime expressions and get interval without a function.

You basically need [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. >expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are >used in the calculation.

and your query would then be

```
$query ="select email from domain_detail where DATEDIFF(expiry_date, curdate() = 5)";
```